# Shapes in a lattice: area less than 1 or π/2?

Tags: geometry, area, integer-lattices

A problem from [cut-the-knot](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/lattice.shtml):

> Imagine a rectangular grid (lattice in the math parlance) with the distance between the nodes equal to 1. Also, let there be given a shape with the area less than 1 but otherwise arbitrary. Show that it's possible to place this shape onto the plane in such a manner that no grid nodes will fall inside the shape.

[image]

The proof just uses translation. If rotation is considered, can the area be less than *π*/2 instead of 1?

I'm thinking a circle with area *π*/2 just touching 4 grid nodes. Intuitively, any shape slightly less than this circle can be rotated to avoid these 4 grid nodes. But I can neither prove it nor think out a counter example.

Comment: With some constraints like maximal width/height, this could be true. However this is an open problem, and you might have better luck on https://mathoverflow.stackexchange.com